# mongodb deleted documents remain in another collection that referenced them

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following example:

```
const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  test: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Test" }],
});

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
});

TestSchema.index({ date: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
```

When a document gets automatically deleted from the `Test` collection, they still remain referenced into the `Example` collection. What can I modify so that it gets deleted from the `Example` collection field too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is not a relational database.

If there are relationships between documents in different collections, it is up to the application to create, remove, and maintain the relation.

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb,you must delete Test in two steps, delete it from Example then delete it itself.